# WPF - Pagination and Event handling for unknown number of elements

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, events

I'm pretty new to WPF (and in a professional setting, C#), and have been presented a challenge to identify and fix a possible memory leak in one of our apps.
The app integrates with Shopify, in order to be able to use the webapp inside the WPF app (integrates payment systems, shopify orders, product listing, etc.).

The custom control I am refactoring, originally had some "scrollview" (for the categories/products to be displayed and navigated around), with 9 elements being displayed at each time. The problem with it, was that with each scroll down (and loading of +9 products) they would stay loaded in memory, eventually blowing up the app (not exactly blowing up, but filling memory until the host runs out of it, slowing the app down to a crawl).

After talking to my senior and brainstorming possible solutions, we came to the conclusion that the best option in both "simplicity" and user-experience, would be to paginate the content.

So in order to accomplish that, we have the "old view" (has methods to populate a child user control - each "product", getting updated product info from shopify's api, and it also has the navigation events/logic) and I have created a new user control, responsible for "containing" the other user control (this is in essence a page of products or container), where I keep track of current product IDs (to execute shopify API query each time we navigate - essentially loading 9 products every time the user navigates back and forward) and the current "page" the user is browsing.

I am trying to retrieve 2*9 products (if the chosen category/brand of product has more than 9 items - the "2 page loading method" runs, if not we default to try and load 9+1 products), on the first "pass/iteration", in order to "fool" the user and not having them wait for the query result to come (every time we query, we download product info and images, etc.). Essentially loading 1 page ahead every time (and keeping track of the current page index, previous page index and next page index - for each of these indexes there is a productID that matches them at any given time - they are queried to the API each time we need to retrieve them). Example: page0 - id:123; page1 -  id:321; page2 - id:456. click next -> page0 - id:321; page1 - id:456; page2 - id:232. edit: The page/id that was discarded/ isn't in view anymore, gets disposed via Dispose().

I am retrieving the product IDs I need to keep track of fine - I haven't, yet, implemented the current page logic, but I am pretty sure I will have to make this UC communicate with the old UC - to send and retrieve current page index - but as I am pretty new to WPF - I don't understand how I go about wiring up/firing button events from the other UC in this "container" thing or how to access them (I have tried the namespace "way" to try and call the old user control, but I can't call it in code-behind (thus not being able to access the buttons via dot syntax).

There probably is an example of this somewhere online that I could refactor and base my code on, but I am currently not able to find it without any help from someone more knowledgeable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the virtualisation options for some of the WPF controls -> https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/virtualization-in-wpf-using-virtualizingstackpanel/.  This could resolve you memory issues as it only renders whats visible on the screen,

Comment: @newky2k I have looked into the "VirtualizingPanel & VirtualizingStackPanel" methods and what they do. The panel where the products are being shown to the user were already contained in a VirtualizedPanel with IsVirtualizing set to true and VirtualizingMode set to Recycling.  
I have done some quick maths and the memory expense is "expected" and there's no other way around it (the images have to be in memory, downloaded or in cache). One solution revolves around taking a # of products and just keeping 3 pages (at best) in memory and swapping them around as needed. 
thanks for the help :)